# What is the Best Practive to user Hibernate DetachedCriteria?

Tags: hibernate

I have used DetachedCriteria in the web application and would like to know what is the best practice to use it, so will achieve best ORM performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no performance hit to using DetachedCriteria, it is simply a convenience object which allows you to construct a criteria outside of a Hibernate Session.

When you go to execute a query you will by necessity have to attach to a session to execute your query.

Since in Hibernate you can detach objects from the session, this allows non-session aware code to send queries to the backend for further processing.